# How to store values from JSON to key-value pairs

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to fetch values from JSON below on the basis of their nodes in key-value pairs. I need to store values of JSON fields in a list or collection. I tried with the code below, but it did not give the desired output.  How can I achieve this?

As of now, I'm doing this:

```
HttpPostedFileBase JSfile = Request.Files["UploadedJSFile"];

if ((JSfile != null) && (JSfile.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(JSfile.FileName))
{
   BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(JSfile.InputStream);
   byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(JSfile.ContentLength);

   string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData);
   JArray jsonVal = JArray.Parse(result) as JArray;

   foreach (JObject content in jsonVal.Children<JObject>())
   {
      foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
      {
         filters.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value.ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

But it's not giving the desired output.
I want all values with their nodes like: `herobanner.landing.copies.watchvideo`

Here is my JSON:

```
[{
    "country": "en-in",
    "heroBanner": {
        "landing": {
            "copies": {
                "watchVideo": "watch the video",
                "scrollDown": [
                    "READ INSPIRING STORIES",
                    ""
                ],
                "banner": [
                    "make your",
                    "first move this",
                    "valentine's Day"
                ]
            },
            "background": {
                "desktop": "assets/images/millions-hero-1.jpg"
            },
            "foreground": {
                "desktop": ""
            },
            "video": {
                "youtubeId": "buwcDIcFR8I"
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Try using `dynamic` if you don't care about strongly-type solution. It will allow you to access any property you've given.

Comment: can u pls give me the line of code that i cn use

Comment: `dynamic foo = JObject.Parse(jsonText); string bar = foo.Bar;` see [link](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/c-dynamic-object-and-json-serialization-with-json-net/)

Comment: I would like to store each and every key from json and its value in some collection. For dynamic, i should know which key is being used. that will not solve my purpose

Answer (score 0):

You could make a recursive extension method to flatten the JToken hierarchy to a Dictionary:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> Flatten(this JToken token)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Flatten(token, dict);
        return dict;
    }

    private static void Flatten(JToken token, Dictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        switch (token.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                foreach (JProperty prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
                {
                    Flatten(prop.Value, dict);
                }
                break;

            case JTokenType.Array:
                foreach (JToken child in token.Children())
                {
                    Flatten(child, dict);
                }
                break;

            default:
                dict.Add(token.Path, ((JValue)token).Value);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this, assuming `jsonVal` is a JToken of some kind (e.g. JArray or JObject):

```
var dict = jsonVal.Flatten();
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sVrM2e